# Count the number of non blank entries in each field grouped by another field oracle sql database

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

Hi I have the following data in an oracle sql dab:

```
AS_OF_DATE  TICKER  SCORE_1 SCORE_2
'20130301'  'BCO'   0.9 0.3
'20130409'  'BCO'   0.8 0.2
'20130501'  'BCO'   0.4 0.9
'20130601'  'BCO'   0.6 0.6
'20130701'  'BCO'       0.2
'20130801'  'BCO'   0.7 0.1
'20130901'  'BCO'   0.9 0.4
'20131001'  'BCO'   0.7 0.5
'20131101'  'BCO'   0.5 
'20130701'  'WGO'   0.1 
'20130801'  'WGO'   0.7 
'20130901'  'WGO'   0.8 
'20131001'  'WGO'   0.1 0.9
'20131101'  'WGO'   0.2 0.8
'20131201'  'WGO'   0.6 0.5
```

I need to count the number of tickers for each date for each score.

i.e.

```
AS_OF_DATE  Count of SCORE_2        Count of SCORE_1
'20130601'         1                   1
'20130701'         1                   1
'20130801'         1                   2
'20130901'         1                   2
'20131001'         1                   1
'20131101'                             1
```

I've been trying to use GROUP BY and COUNT without success.  Thanks!!!

```
    SELECT COUNT(table.TICKER),
    table.AS_OF_DATE,
    table.SCORE_1,
    table.SCORE_2

    FROM table WHERE RowNum <= 200
    GROUP BY table.AS_OF_DATE
```

Comment: Edit your question and show your attempted query.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Gordon, does my question make sense now.?  Apologies!... only my second question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table.AS_OF_DATE,
       COUNT(table.SCORE_2) "Count of SCORE_2",
       COUNT(table.SCORE_1) "Count of SCORE_1"
FROM   table 
WHERE  RowNum <= 200
GROUP BY table.AS_OF_DATE
```

COUNT function calculates the number of not null attributes. Another point re COUNT is that it returns not null value, so in your case instead of empty value you will see 0.

Comment: Thanks Maxim!!  :)